# Is there a way to enable VSYNC on RPI4?

Tags: hdmi, video, lxde

I am using Raspbian Buster with default LXDE/Openbox configuration. Screen tearing when moving windows around or watching videos is very noticeable. Is there a way to enable VSYNC on RPI4 using HDMI?